# No constituent of type 'PromiseSettledResult<any>' is callable

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I am getting the below error while building (ng build) my project on local. it is running fine on local host.

```
error TS2349: This expression is not callable.

No constituent of type 'PromiseSettledResult\<any\>' is callable at  
results.forEach((result, index) =\>{...})
```

My code is like this for checkImageUrl method where i am getting the error

```
async checkImageUrl(type) {
        const myArray = type === 'new' ? this.newArray : this.oldArray;
        const promises = myArray.map(item => {
          if (!(item?.imageURL.includes('http'))) {
            return this.getImage(item?.imageURL)
              .then(imageBlob => {
                const bolbImageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
                const safeImageUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(bolbImageUrl);
                return safeImageUrl;
              })
              .catch(_error => Promise.resolve(item?.imageURL));
          } else {
            return Promise.resolve(item?.imageURL);
          }
    });

    try {
      const results: PromiseSettledResult<any>[] = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
      // const results = await Promise.allSettled(promises) as PromiseSettledResult<MyPromiseResult>[];
      results.forEach((result, index) => {    // -------------> error at this line number
     if (result.status === 'fulfilled' && result.value) {
        myArray[index].imageURL = result.value;
     }
     });
   } catch (_error) {
      this.spinner.hide();
    }}
```

and my getImage method is :

```
getImage(docId): Promise<Blob> {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.http.get(BaseUrl + '/'+docId, { responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response' })
            .subscribe((response: HttpResponse<Blob>) => {
               const blob = response.body;
               resolve(blob);
            }, error => {
               reject(error);
           });
      });
   }
```

I also tried to provide the type of results variable to this:

```
const results: PromiseSettledResult\<MyPromiseResult\>\[\] = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
```

where myPromiseResult is decleared as: `type MyPromiseResult = SafeResourceUrl | string;`

But still getting the error

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Please provide a [mcve] that produces the error when pasted into https://www.typescriptlang.org/play.